# Need regex to match rather similar URL patterns

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I need a regex (to be used in .htaccess) with the following attributes, capturing up to a three digit number and the text following it:

Match:

```
/1-my-blog-post/  
/100-another-blog-post/
```

Do not match:

```
/1/  
/100/
```

So far I have:

```
RewriteRule ^(\d{1,2,3}\w+)/$ /post.php?s=$1 [L]
```

Thanks in advance because it's really bugging me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see some problems in your regex

```
^(\d{1,2,3}\w+)/$
```

`\d{1,2,3}` has to be `\d{1,3}` you just give the min and the max amount

`\w` includes also numbers and `_` but not `-`

Maybe a better solution would be

```
^/(\d{1,3}[a-zA-Z-]+)/$
```

See it [here online on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2ufpn)

`[a-zA-Z-]` is a character class that matches a character from what is defined inside. I don't know if the letter range a-zA-Z is fine for you, but you can add any character you want to match into the class like this `[a-zA-ZöäüÖÄÜ&?-]`

Comment: It did'nt match exactly what I wanted to do, but I figured it out from your answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In Perl it would be

```
^\d{1,3}[^\d].*
```

I'm assuming the character after the 3 numbers cannot be number, of course, and it's from the start of the string recived (as you put it in your example)

Comment: I suggest you try this, as most regex in other languages are copied from Perl.